# Book Recommendation: Price Theory

Tags: reference-request, price-theory

Can someone please recommend a book or a chapter from a book which provides a good and clear explanation of price theory. How prices are determined what they reflect and how they serve as allocaters of resources.

Answer (score 7):

### [The Applied Theory of Price](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0023785209)

*by Donald N. McCloskey*

McCloskey published the book ([pdf](http://www.deirdremccloskey.com/docs/price.pdf)) for free now.

The Chicago school's other economists also published their books on price theory (see Milton Friedman's and George Stigler's).

Comment: thank you i will have a look. what level is this. i am looking for undergraduate level

Comment: Just to add that this book is exceptionally good.

Answer (score 3):

Any decent basic introductionary economics textbook will answer that for you. Principles of economics by Mankiw gives some nice intuition. if you a looking for a little more advanced stuff, try Intermediate microeconomics by Varian.

Comment: i tried mankiw's book. I did not find it to be the best on this topic

Answer (score 2):

I really like David Friedman's [Price Theory](http://www.daviddfriedman.com/Academic/Price_Theory/PThy_ToC.html) for this material. I feel it really marries the intuition to the math. If you prefer a dead-tree version, you can usually find a used one for a few bucks online.

Answer (score 0):

Chicago Price Theory by Milton, Mulligan & Murphy is interesting take on the price theory.

Answer (score 0):

"Principles of Economics" by N. Gregory Mankiw, is suitable for undergraduate-level economics courses and provides a clear and accessible introduction to economic principles, including price theory.